# Regex to Match hours in the format 9.30am-8.45pm

Tags: .net, regex

I have got this regex `"(\d{1,2}[aM|Am|am|pm|Pm|pM]{2}-\d{1,2}[aM|Am|am|pm|Pm|pM]{2})"`

which matches strings like the following: `9am-8pm`

but I want to be able to match these strings with another regex: 9.30am-8.30pm

I have got the following regex but it doesnt match anything:

```
(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}[am|AM|aM|Am][pm|PM|Pm|pM]-\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}[am|AM|aM|Am][pm|PM|Pm|pM])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `.` otherwise it will match any character(except newline).

Make `am` and `pm` case insensitive.

Better you should use it like this:

```
/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(am|pm)-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(am|pm)$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

since `'.'` is a special character, you have to escape it as `\.`

```
(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[am|AM|aM|Am][pm|PM|Pm|pM]-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[am|AM|aM|Am][pm|PM|Pm|pM])
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. `.` is going to match ANY character.  You should escape it as `\.`
2. You've changed the am/pm construct so it doesn't match the same way

Does the following suit your needs?

`(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[aApP]{1}[mM]{1}-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[aApP]{1}[mM]{1})`